# Encoding and Decoding in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, encoding

I'm working on an mobile app with Ionic 3, and am using Laravel's api.
and i'm having a problem inserting an url link into mysql database, i tried the btoa() function to encode but it didn't help because there's still a '/' in the encoded string that disrupt my api route.

Any Help ? Thanks !

Comment: `btoa` converts a string to base64, which includes `/` in it's character set. Consider using url-safe base64 instead (replace `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`).

Comment: I'd just do it manually. Eg: `btoa(yourString).replace("+", "-").replace("/", "_")`. And don't forget to do the reverse when you need decode it.

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot about replace() ! anyway thanks a lot it worked !! :D